# Find the Galois group of a quotient field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

The task is to determine
$Gal(L|K)$ for $L=\mathbb{F}_2(X)$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_2(X^2)$

I'm not sure what $K$ looks like. I assume $\mathbb{F}_2(X^2)\cong  \{ \frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}: P,Q \in F_2[X^2] \}$.

My first attempt was to guess a $K$-basis of $L$, namely $(1,X)$ but it didn't work because I can't get odd exponents in the denominator. Therefore I assume it is an extension of degree $>2$.

On the other hand I also realized that $irr(X,\mathbb{F}_2(X^2))=T^2-X^2$, hence $[\mathbb{F}_2(X^2)[X]:\mathbb{F}_2(X^2)]=2$ but here I get confused.

If $\mathbb{F}_2(X^2)[X]$ is a field, then it should be closed under inverse and thus it contains $\frac{1}{X}$. Does this mean $\mathbb{F}_2(X^2)[X]=\mathbb{F}_2(X)$?

I'd be very thankful if you could clarify the situation.

Comment: $\Bbb F_2(X^2)[X]$ is just as much a field as $\Bbb Q[\sqrt2]$ is. Which is to say, it is definitely a field (for instance we have $\frac1X=\frac1{X^2}X$). Also, note that $L/K$ is not a Galois extension, as it's not separable. It is, in fact, the simplest example of a non-separable extension (or possibly the second simplest, on account of $\Bbb F_2$ behaving strangely at times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that $(1,X)$ is a $K$-basis of $L$.

- First notice that $\mathbb{F}_2[X]\subset L$. For $P\in\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, one can write $$P=\sum_{}p_{2k}X^{2k} + \left(\sum_{}p_{2k+1}X^{2k}\right)X$$
- Then remember that the Frobenius is $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear : this implies, among other things, that for $P\in\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, $P(X^2)=P(X)^2$.
- The result follows : for $(P,Q)\in\mathbb{F}_2[X]^2$ and $Q\neq 0$, just write $$\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}=\frac{P(X)Q(X)}{Q(X)^2}=\frac{P(X)Q(X)}{Q(X^2)}$$

which is therefore in the $K$ vector space spanned by $(1,X)$ inside $L$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm almost there. I'f I'm not wrong, to conclude after the last step I should notice that $\frac{1}{Q(X^2)} \in \mathbb{F}_2(X^2) $. and $P(X)Q(X) \in \mathbb{F}_2[X]$. But then would follow that $[L:K]=2$ and since both identity and $X \mapsto -X$ are automorphisms, then $|Gal(L|K)|=2$ hence the extension is Galois. However someone commented that this is the simplest non Galois extension. (Although I'm not sure why it is not separable). Where am I wrong?

Comment: For the first part, yes, this is what you should notice.

For the second part, notice that $X\mapsto -X$ is actually the identity ! Indeed,  $-1=1$ in characteristic $2$. This is why it's not separable. Another way to say the same thing, is to notice that $T^2-X^2 $ is irreducible in $K[T]$ but in $L[T]$, $T^2-X^2=(T-X)^2$ (again, the frobenius is $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear.)